# how can I compare old records with new ones then import just the new ones

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to work with [Biometric Device Integration](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/master/hr_biometric_machine/) module to import attendances from a biometric device but I found that it deletes attendances after every import thing that I don't want. so I remove the function that it deletes attendances from my machine but here again I found that when I import the function duplicates the attendances

what I want is that it compares old records(attendances) with new ones and import just new records.

```html
    @classmethod
    def import_data_classmethod(
            cls, biometric_machine, biometric_data_obj, biometric_user_obj,):
        attendances = biometric_machine.getattendance()
        # Sorted elements using user_id and timestamp
        attendances.sort(key=lambda x: (x.user_id, x.timestamp))
        for attendance in attendances:
            user = biometric_user_obj.search([
                ['biometric_id', '=', int(attendance.user_id), ], ], )
            if not attendance.action_perform:
                continue
            if not user.employee_id:
                biometric_data_obj.create(
                    {'biometric_user_id': user.id,
                     'datetime': attendance.timestamp,
                     'action_perform': attendance.action_perform, }, )
                continue

                
            biometric_data_obj.create_hr_attendace(
                user.employee_id.id, attendance.timestamp,
                attendance.action_perform,
                user.biometric_device.id,)
        #biometric_machine.clean_attendance()
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    @classmethod
    def import_data_classmethod(
            cls, biometric_machine, biometric_data_obj, biometric_user_obj,):
        attendances = biometric_machine.getattendance()
        # Sorted elements using user_id and timestamp
        attendances.sort(key=lambda x: (x.user_id, x.timestamp))
        for attendance in attendances:
            user = biometric_user_obj.search([
                ['biometric_id', '=', int(attendance.user_id), ], ], )


            del_atten_ids = biometric_data_obj.search([('biometric_user_id','=',user.id),('datetime','=',str(attendance.timestamp))])
            if del_atten_ids:
                            # hr_attendance.unlink(cr,uid,del_atten_ids)
                print "nothing to do"
            elif not del_atten_ids: 





                if not attendance.action_perform:
                    continue
                if not user.employee_id:
                    biometric_data_obj.create(
                    {'biometric_user_id': user.id,
                     'datetime': attendance.timestamp,
                     'action_perform': attendance.action_perform, }, )
                    continue


                biometric_data_obj.create_hr_attendace(
                user.employee_id.id, attendance.timestamp,
                attendance.action_perform,
                user.biometric_device.id,)
        #biometric_machine.clean_attendance()
```